# Which view do I have to use to make the order of the images random in Node Gallery Slideshow?

Tags: views, 6, media

I'm currently using [Node Gallery Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/node_gallery_slideshow) module for displaying a gallery with a slideshow. It works correctly, but when displaying the images, the order of them is sequential, and I haven't found a way to make it random - at least on the admin interface...
So which view do I have to use to get a random order.

Thanks!

Comment: -1? Why? Any explanations would be appreciated... I really don't understand the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under admin/build/views/list, look for node_gallery_gallery_image_views. Your probably looking for the 'view all image thumbnails' display here to have it randomize a full gallery. The current display order is based on your node gallery image weight so you'll want to remove these under 'Sort Criteria' (click the up down arrow icon to remove these settings).

After that, you want to add a sort order criteria, 'Global: Random' to have the results of the view sorted randomly.

Note: this will apply to all of your galleries since it is accepting an argument of the parent gallery node object. If you want this just to apply to one specific node_gallery, you'll need to clone the display first and adjust this argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Hmm, I realized that it seems like it's not enough to remove the sort criteria only on the *"view all image thumbnails"* display, and set *"Global: Random"* as a new criteria, because it didn't randomize my content yet - but if I set these on the "Default" display, it really randomizes my galleries. Yes, this way it unfortunately randomizes my galleries in all the cases. I don't know why NG Slideshow doesn't use a separated view. An interesting thing: I have to clear the cache tables all the time if I want my images to be really randomized on every refreshes! Any idea?

Comment: Which display are you trying to target? Are you removing the previous sort orders on that display (using the override option so it doesn't effect your other displays)? It sounds like it is still trying to use one of the pre-existing sort options so sorting by 'title' first and then by random would obviously not be randomizing..

Comment: The interesting thing is that now I have already set "Global: Random" as the default display, and let it to be applied to all the displays, and yes, of course I have removed the original *"Node Gallery: Image: Image weight asc"* and *"Node: Nid desc"* filters. But it's still true that I have to flush cache tables if I want my contents to be randomized again! I don't really understand, *"Caching: None"* is also set in this view. It would be great if you had an idea to solve that problem to let my gallery's content be randomized on EVERY refreshes with F5, not just after I flush cache tables.

Comment: do you have page caching turned on within drupal (under performance settings)? If you're caching the pages, this would occur after the view had generated and there's not much you can do about it within the view. The strategy a lot of high-performance, heavily cached sites will employ to randomize a list is to generate it with a view and then randomize it client-side using jquery.

Comment: NO, *"Caching mode"* is set to **"Disabled"**!! Then why the heck doesn't it randomize my content on every F5 refreshes? I simply don't understand why I have to flush my cache tables for that.